# Prove $\frac{1}{v(B_{\varepsilon})}\iint_{S_{\varepsilon}}zf{\rm d}S\underset{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}{\rightarrow}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a continuously
> differentiable function. Let $S_\varepsilon,B_\varepsilon$ be the
> sphere and ball of radius $\varepsilon$ around the origin,
> respectively. Show that
> $$\frac{1}{v(B_{\varepsilon})}\iint_{S_{\varepsilon}}zf(x,y,z){\rm  d}S\underset{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}{\rightarrow}\frac{\partial
>  f}{\partial z}(0,0,0).$$
> Here $v$ signifies volume.

My strategy is to divide $S_\varepsilon$ into two  hemispheres $S_\varepsilon^+$ and $S_\varepsilon^{-}$ according to the sign of $z$. Then we can write
$$ \iint_{S_{\varepsilon}}zf(x,y,z){\rm d}S=\iint_{S_{\varepsilon}^{+}}z\left[f(x,y,z)-f(x,y,-z)\right]{\rm d}S. $$
Now I would like to substitute $$ f(x,y,z)-f(x,y,-z)=\int_{-z}^{z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,u){\rm d}u, $$ then turn the entire expression into a triple integral over $B_\varepsilon$. Here things get a bit messy, mostly because of having both $z$ and $u$, and I wonder if there's a more elegant way.

As a side note, I realize the goal should be reaching something that looks like $$ \frac{1}{v(B_{\varepsilon})}\iiint_{B_{\varepsilon}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z){\rm d}V $$ since this is simply an average, and it approaches the desired value $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0)$.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps I'm messing up but should it be $\frac{1}{\epsilon v(B_{\epsilon})}\int_{S_{\epsilon}}zf(x,y,z)\,dS$ instead? The idea is to apply the divergence theorem to $(0,0,f)$, and the extra $\epsilon$ in the denominator normalizes the radial vector $(x,y,z)$ to give the outward unit normal on the sphere $S_{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
zf(x,y,z)=\varepsilon n\cdot(0,0,f(x,y,z)),
$$
where $n$ is the unit normal at each point of $S_\varepsilon$. It follows from the Divergence Theorem that
$$\iint_{S_{\varepsilon}}zf(x,y,z)\,{\rm  d}S=
\varepsilon\iiint_{B_{\varepsilon}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(x,y,z)\,{\rm  d}V.
$$
Finally, by the continuity of the derivative we obtain
$$\frac{1}{{\color{red}\varepsilon}\, v(B_{\varepsilon})}\iint_{S_{\varepsilon}}zf(x,y,z){\rm  d}S\underset{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}{\rightarrow}\frac{\partial
 f}{\partial z}(0,0,0).
$$